# Python for images filter - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, opencv, filter, scikit-image, nonetype

I have trying to put differents filters on images with python, opencv, skimage, etc. This operation will help me for a neural training program. But I a problem right now with my filter code.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import skimage.io as io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageFilter
from skimage.util import random_noise
from skimage.transform import rotate, AffineTransform, warp
from skimage.filters import gaussian
import shutil
from PIL import Image
import warnings
import time
import os.path

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
print("hello")  # Affiche "hello"

# Localisation du dossier source
source_images = ''
# Localisation du dossier destination
desti = ''
source_labels = ''  

#filtre mexican_hat (find edges)/ Affiche un filtre sombre et fais ressortir les contours de l'objet sur l'integralité de l'image
def Mexican(img):   #fonction Mexican
    filter = np.array([[0,0,-1,0,0],[0,-1,-2,-1,0],[-1,-2,16,-2,-1],[0,-1,-2,-1,0],[0,0,-1,0,0]])
    mexican_hat_img1=cv2.filter2D(img,-1,filter)    #paramètres du filtre
    return mexican_hat_img1     #renvoi de l'image filtrée

#filtre couleur (0=Blue,1=Green,2=Red)/ Affiche du Rouge, du Bleu ou du Vert sur l'integralité de l'image
def exponential_function(channel, exp):
    channel_color =channel
    table = np.array([min((i**exp), 255) for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8") # creating table for exponent
    channel_color = cv2.LUT(channel_color, table)
    return channel_color

def tone(img, number):  #fonction Blue/Green/Red
    img_color = img
    for i in range(3):
        if i == number:
            img_color[:, :, i] = exponential_function(img_color[:, :, i], 1.10) # applying exponential function on slice
        else:
            img_color[:, :, i] = 0 # setting values of all other slices to 0 to blue 1to green 2to red
    return img_color

def desti_labels():
    count=1
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(source_labels)):
        param0 = str(count) + "Blur" + '.txt'   
        param1 = str(count) + "Noise" + '.txt'
        param2 = str(count) + "Sharpen" + '.txt'
        param3 = str(count) + "Blue" +  '.txt'
        param4 =str(count) + "Green" + '.txt'
        param5 =str(count) + "Red" + '.txt'
        param6 =str(count) + "Sepia" + '.txt'
        param7 =str(count) + "Mexican" + '.txt'
        param8 =str(count) + '.txt'
        src ="/home/melanie/Desktop/test-filtre/crease/final-crease"+filename
        #dst0 ="/Desktop/Quality_Inspection/Defects_location_for_metal_surface/Classe 1 crease/test-augmentor"+param0
        #dst1 ="/Desktop/Quality_Inspection/Defects_location_for_metal_surface/Classe 1 crease/test-augmentor"+param1
        #dst2 ="/home/alternant2/augment_env_TP_folder/Test_data100/Final/"+param2
        dst3 ="/home/melanie/Desktop/test-filtre/crease/final-crease"+param3
        dst4 ="/home/melanie/Desktop/test-filtre/crease/final-crease"+param4
        dst5 ="/home/melanie/Desktop/test-filtre/crease/final-crease"+param5
        #dst6 ="/Desktop/Quality_Inspection/Defects_location_for_metal_surface/Classe 1 crease/test-augmentor"+param6
        dst7 ="/home/melanie/Desktop/test-filtre/crease/final-crease"+param7
        dst8 ="/home/melanie/Desktop/test-filtre/crease/final-crease"+param8

        shutil.copyfile(src,dst3)
        shutil.copyfile(src,dst4)
        shutil.copyfile(src,dst5)
        shutil.copyfile(src,dst7)
        shutil.copyfile(src,dst8)
        count+=1
        print("count", count)
    return

lst_img=os.listdir(source_images)
print(lst_img)
def dest_images():
    count_img=1
    for filename in sorted(lst_img): #Pour tous les fichiers dans source
        img=cv2.imread(source_images+filename)  #choix du fichier
        
        print(type(img))        #Affiche le type de l'image(dans notre cas ndarray)
        img=cv2.imread(source_images+filename)  #choix du fichier
        img_blue = tone(img,0)      #appel fonction Blue
        img=cv2.imread(source_images+filename)  #choix du fichier
        img_green =tone(img,1)      #appel fonction Green
        img=cv2.imread(source_images+filename)  #choix du fichier
        img_red = tone(img,2)       #appel fonction Red
        img=cv2.imread(source_images+filename)  #choix du fichier       
        img_mexican = Mexican(img)  #appel fonction Mexican
        
        #CONFIG 1
        new_filename=str(count_img)     # Remove the 4 last character ==> .PNG i.e.     
        print("A few moments later...")                 # Afficher "A few moments later..."
        time.sleep(3)                           # Delai d'attente
        cv2.imwrite(new_filename+'Blue.JPG',img_blue)       #Enregistre le filtre Blue
        cv2.imwrite(new_filename+'Green.JPG',img_green) #Enregistre le filtre Green
        cv2.imwrite(new_filename+'Red.JPG',img_red)     #Enregistre le filtre Red
        cv2.imwrite(new_filename+'Mexican.JPG',img_mexican) #Enregistre le filtre Mexican
        cv2.imwrite(new_filename+'.JPG',img)
        count_img+=1                #Enregistre l'image originale
    return

os.chdir(desti)         # "Dans le fichier appelé desti"
dest_images()
desti_labels()
```

When I run this code, I see this error on my terminal :

```
 hello
['final-crease', 'img_01_425382900_00002.jpg']
<class 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/melanie/Desktop/test-de-merde-3.py", line 115, in <module>
    dest_images()
  File "/home/melanie/Desktop/test-de-merde-3.py", line 88, in dest_images
    img_blue = tone(img,0)              #appel fonction Blue
  File "/home/melanie/Desktop/test-de-merde-3.py", line 42, in tone
    img_color[:, :, i] = exponential_function(img_color[:, :, i], 1.10) # applying exponential function on slice
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have to admet, I don't really know what to do. Unfortunatly, I don't find the solution. If you have an idea, I take it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
print(type(img))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

The line `img=cv2.imread(source_images+filename)` is not finding the files and thus returns None. When you try to index on line 42, you get the error because you cannot slice None.

--Try `img=cv2.imread(source_images+"/"+filename)` to change the directory.--
This will not work when `source_images=0`

Comment: I tried your solution but the problem is still here

Comment: is `FinalCrease` an image?

Comment: FinalCrease is a folder with images in it.

Answer (score 0):

- import cv2
- im =cv2.imread('/name.jpg')